# What is a Parent table and a Child table in Database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I just want to know what is a parent table and what is a child table in databases. Can you please show me an example so I understand how it works please.

Thank You

Comment: Been googling, not really explaining it really well bud

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Child tables and parent tables are just normal database tables, but they’re linked in a way that's described by a parent–child relationship.

It’s usually used to specify where one table’s value refers to the value in another table (usually a primary key of another table).

For example, imagine a news article. This could be represented by a table called `articles` and has fields for `id`, `headline`, `body`, `published_date` and `author`. But instead of placing a name in the `author` field, you could instead put the ID value of a user in a separate table—maybe called `authors`—that has information on authors such as `id`, `name`, and `email`.

Therefore, if you need to update an author’s name, you only need to do so in the `authors` (parent) table; because the `articles` (child) table only contains the ID of the corresponding `author` record.

Hope this helps you understand better.

Comment: If you have multiple articles pointing to one author, wouldn't the `authors` table be the parent table?

Comment: Is there any good book on database for beginners, I would like to know,  It is much confusing when searching the books for beginners  in amazon.

Comment: tldr for a given constraint the parent is the one with the unique key

Answer (score 19):

Be aware you can have relationships that appear to be parent-child but are not, for instance when lookup tables are being used.

The distinction is that in a true **parent-child** relationship, **child records typically don't stand on their own very well** - they are detail records for the parent and are not useful without the parent table info.  A person can own multiple cars in the DMV database, but you wouldn't want child records in the CARS table without a parent record in the OWNERS table - it would be nearly useless data.

On the other hand, if I am using a **lookup table** to expand a code to something more meaningful, or to constrain data entry to acceptable values, then the **"child" record can still be useful (can stand alone)** if the lookup table is deleted.  I could still have the sex information as "M" or "F" even if I no longer have the lookup table to expand that to "Male" or "Female".

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it is the only one that explains the difference between `lookup` relationships and `parent-child` relationships.

Comment: In the "lookup table" example,  the "child" record might contain `genderId` pointing at a lookup table , where `genderId=1` is "Male" and `genderId=2` is "Female". Does that mean the lookup table is the "parent"?   Interesting [Salesforce article at this link](https://www.salesforceben.com/relationships-in-salesforce/) echoes the idea posted here; that  in a "master-child" relationship (strongly coupled), "Parent record is required in order to save a child record.", whereas in a  "lookup" relationship (loosely coupled), "Parent record is not required when creating a child record."

Answer (score 13):

Parent - The entity on the "one" (/1) side of a relation with another table

Child - The entity on the "many" (/N/*) side of a relation with another table

Comment: `Parent` <-- `Child`.  The child **points** to the parent. So each child **knows** who its parent is. And each child has exactly one parent. A parent entity contains no information as to who its children are.

Answer (score 5):

A child table tends to be one where it has one or more foreign keys pointing at some other table(s). Note that a child table can itself be a parent to some OTHER table as well.

Answer (score 3):

Those terms are used in database relationships.

for example u have two table,

1.Manifast

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| manifast_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| description | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| title       | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

2. day_sequence

> ```
> +-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
> +-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> | day_sequence_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
> | day_number      | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
> | day_start       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
> | manifast_id     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
> +-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
> ```

if u want to connect those two tables,u need to use the command with following format.

```
> ALTER TABLE child_table_name ADD FOREIGN KEY (P_ID) REFERENCES
> parent_table_name (P_ID)
```

and so it become.

```
> ALTER TABLE day_sequence ADD CONSTRAINT fk_manifast FOREIGN KEY
> (manifast_Id) REFERENCES manifast(manifast_Id);
```

In summary,
Child table is a table which has foreign key,and is connected from others table.
Parent table has no foreign key and connect to other.
[ Note : This ans is just for connecting two tables ]

Comment: **Parent table has no foreign key and connect to other**  connect to other what?. I I mean table or fields?