# What are parent and child tables?

Tags: database, oracle

I'm new to Oracle and was watching a tutorial on it. In the tutorial, the presenter mentioned parent and child table several times but I could not understand what they mean. Can someone please explain it to me with an example?

Comment: Can you link to the tutorial so that others can see what the presenter means in context?

Comment: without more context, hard to say. Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880921/what-is-a-parent-table-and-a-child-table-in-database?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The are probably poor choices for names, but everyone uses them because the names are convenient and because of how the entities appear in an entity relationship diagrams.

A child table has a reference (aka a foreign key) to the parent table.

Eg an employee table that had a (foreign key) column called department_id, whose values were found in the department table's id (primary key) column would represent a (many-to-one) child/parent relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Child tables and parent tables are just normal database tables, but they’re linked in a way that's described by a parent–child relationship.

It’s usually used to specify where one table’s value refers to the value in another table (usually a primary key of another table).

For example, imagine a news article. This could be represented by a table called articles and has fields for id, headline, body, published_date and author. But instead of placing a name in the author field, you could instead put the ID value of a user in a separate table—maybe called authors—that has information on authors such as id, name, and email.

Therefore, if you need to update an author’s name, you only need to do so in the authors (parent) table; because the articles (child) table only contains the ID of the corresponding author record.

Source: [What is a Parent table and a Child table in Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880921/what-is-a-parent-table-and-a-child-table-in-database)

Comment: must have missed....marked it..

Comment: What a shame ! exact copy of the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7880921/what-is-a-parent-table-and-a-child-table-in-database

Comment: What an ignorance...marked as wiki community...means no rep for me...so no intention to just copy...here ill make an edit also so you can feel comfortable